# Fastest way to concatenate two JS uint8 arrays to a uint16 array?

Tags: javascript, binary, concatenation, typed-arrays

I know this is fairly easy in other languages, but what is the best way to do this in JS if I have two arrays of 8-bit unsigned integers, and would like to concatenate them to one array of unsigned 16 bit integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming both *Arrays* have the same length, use a `for` loop with the [bitwise left shift operator `<<`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3C%3C_%28Left_shift%29);

```
var arr8A = [2, 3, 4], // example
    arr8B = [5, 6, 7];
// code start
var arr16 = new Uint16Array(arr8A.length),
    i;
for (i = 0; i < arr8A.length; ++i)
    arr16[i] = (arr8A[i] << 8) + arr8B[i];
arr16;
```

---

The reverse is similar but you use the [bitwise zero-fill right shift operator `>>>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3E%3E%3E_%28Zero-fill_right_shift%29) and the [bitwise AND operator `&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.26_%28Bitwise_AND%29);

```
// arr16 as above
var arr8A = new Uint8Array(arr16.length),
    arr8B = new Uint8Array(arr16.length),
    i;
for (i = 0; i < arr16.length; ++i) {
    arr8A[i] = arr16[i] >>> 8;
    arr8B[i] = arr16[i] & 255;
}
console.log(arr8A, arr8B);
```

The maximum size numbers you can safely use these operators with are *32-bit integers*.